# MSSQLテーブル用の、bakeから仕上げた登録画面が、キー自動採取を失敗する

Tags: cakephp, sql-server

CAKEPHP3の参考書に従ってbakeコマンドで一連を作成しました。DBをMySQLとしたテーブルの登録画面は無事に操作することができました。
当該テーブルのid列がPrimaryキーで自動採取するタイプでしたが、MySQLだった際は無事にキーを自動採取した上でレコードが登録できていた、ということです。

app.phpをMSSQLと接続するための定義に変更して（勿論同じ構造のテーブルを用意した上で）、bakeで一連を仕上げなおしました。レコードの照会・編集・削除・一覧表示のメソッドは無事動作しますが、登録のメソッドだけ正常に行えません。

CakePHP内蔵サーバに現れていたエラー内容を確認すると、id列がemptyという状況のようでした。
標題のとおりの要因=キーの自動採取に失敗していると推察しています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この状況を打開する手立てはあるのでしょうか？仕上げられたエンティティ内の$_accessibleを編集（'id'=>true　から　'id'=>false　)にしても状況は変わりありませんでした。

ちなみに、MSSQL上の当該テーブルに別の手続き（ManagementStudio）でレコードを登録すると、自動でidが取得されており、DBMS側の問題ではないと受けてとれます。

参考書の中で紹介されたDBMSとは異なるDBMSを選択して、参考書に従った課題の取り組みは無理がありますかね（より実践を意識したくて　DBMSにMSSQLを選択しています）

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->requirePresence('id', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('id');

        $validator
            ->scalar('title')
            ->maxLength('title', 50)
            ->allowEmpty('title');

        $validator
            ->scalar('author')
            ->maxLength('author', 50)
            ->allowEmpty('author');

        $validator
            ->integer('price')
            ->allowEmpty('price');

        return $validator;
    }
```

Comment: SQLServerに作成されたテーブルのid列にidentityが設定されているでしょうか。

Comment: 「キーの自動採取に失敗」「自動でidが取得されており、DBMS側の問題ではない」が両立するとは思えません。

Comment: @htb されています、ManagementStudioでレコード登録する際はIDの自動採取に成功していますし

Comment: ありがとうございます。では、「キーの自動採取に失敗」は誤りかと。

Comment: 採取されているキーが入ってきていない？

Comment: バリデーションエラーですのでBooksTableのvalidationDefaultメソッドの内容を示してください。

Comment: @nojimage 明確なご指示で非常に助かります。本文に提示させて頂きました
ご確認頂けましたら幸いです。

Comment: 入力時にidの有無を検査しているようですが,このコードがMySQLで本当に動くのか謎に思っています.既に回答にもありますがエラーになって当然なのでは…?同じコードはMySQLで動きますか?

Comment: なお、idがプライマリキーとしてDB側で定義されていれば、bakeで上記のようなバリデーションではなく回答のようなコードが生成されるはずです。autoincrementだけでなくプライマリキーも設定するようにしましょう。

Comment: MySQLでの接続でbakeから仕上げた登録画面を検証していたあと
app.phpをMSSQL用に編集したあと、【bake】をしなおしています。
ですでの、全く同じソースが生成されていたのかは正直分からないです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

idフィールドのバリデーションが以下のように設定されているためバリデーションエラーとなり保存できない状況です。

```
    $validator
        ->integer('id') // idは数値
        ->requirePresence('id', 'create') // 新規作成時にidは必須
        ->notEmpty('id'); // idは空であってはならない
```

idが採番されるのはDBへの保存時ですので、保存前には空でなければなりません。

idのバリデーションは以下のようになるべきです。

```
    $validator
        ->integer('id') // idは数値
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');  // 新規作成時にidは空でもよい
```

Comment: bakeコマンドによるコード生成は簡易ですが、バリデーションやアソシエーションなど書き出し結果が意図しない内容になっていることがあります。bake後は書き出しコードを確認して意図した結果になっているか確認するようにしましょう。

Comment: ご指摘頂きましたとおり編集したところ無事画面が登録できるようになりました。
ありがとうございました。

>idが採番されるのはDBへの保存時ですので、保存前には空でなければなりません。
よくよく考えてみればDBMS側でしたね、採取が。
DBMS側の当該テーブルのデザインは確かにNULL不可としているので、この点が悪さしたのかも知れませんね。
何分初めてのことで、どこまでbakeに頼れるのか分からなかったこと、MySQLだった際ではその点も
気にせずにメソッドが生成できていたことで　お騒がせをしてしまいました。

これで参考書での学習を再開できます、非常に助かりました。